# Android - TextInputEditText accepts Alphabets produce issue when I set max length and android:imeOptions="actionNext" not show on Keyboard

Tags: android, layout, android-textinputedittext

I have take TextInputEditText for first name only accepts alphabets but i have got problem.

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tvfnameinput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etFirstname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                android:hint="firstname"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

As you see in above layout i have set maxlength 12 so if  i have enter 12 numeric value then it's not accepts but it's count so i can't able to enter alphabets after entering 12 numeric value.

**NOTE**-: I want just alphabets and my code is working but when i entered numeric value then it's not accept but count as a maxlenght.

**Edit**-:  android:imeOptions="actionNext" not show on Keyboard when i have set  android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

[image]

Comment: your layout is working fine on my device which runs nougat(API version 26).

And I think you also need to add inputType="text" also.

also I ran this on KitKat too and it's working fine.

Comment: @Umair i have set inputType="text" but problem is same, please read once more my problem.

Comment: that's what I am saying your code is working fine. Even if I enter like 50 digits they don't add and after that I add 12 alphabets it add them. Maybe your problem is some device specific.

Comment: @Umair no i am test 2 different device but problem is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

If you want to set only Alphabets then you can use InputFilter instead of digits. Remove this tag `digit` from your layout.

Here is the example that can help you:

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
            int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
        if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
            return src;
        }
        if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
            return src;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
});
```

**Try this one. it is tested by myself and working like charm**

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            boolean keepOriginal = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                char c = source.charAt(i);
                if (isCharAllowed(c)) // put your condition here
                    sb.append(c);
                else
                    keepOriginal = false;
            }
            if (keepOriginal)
                return null;
            else {
                if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                    TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                    return sp;
                } else {
                    return sb;
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean isCharAllowed(char c) {
            Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
            Matcher ms = ps.matcher(String.valueOf(c));
            return ms.matches();
        }
    }});
```

## Input Filter with MaxLength

When using InputFilter the property of EditText is overridden then you can use max length with InputFiler.

**Try this**

```
 InputFilter[] inputFilters = new InputFilter[2];
    inputFilters[0] = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            boolean keepOriginal = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                char c = source.charAt(i);
                if (isCharAllowed(c)) // put your condition here
                    sb.append(c);
                else
                    keepOriginal = false;
            }
            if (keepOriginal)
                return null;
            else {
                if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                    TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                    return sp;
                } else {
                    return sb;
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean isCharAllowed(char c) {
            Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
            Matcher ms = ps.matcher(String.valueOf(c));
            return ms.matches();
        }
    };

    inputFilters[1] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(12);

    editText.setFilters(inputFilters);
```

Comment: sorry bro it's not working when i entered numeric value then it's remove all previous entered alphabets

Comment: Thanks @Vishal Chhodwani your answer is partially resolve my problem not a 100% so i just upvote.

Comment: OK, Thanks for that. May I know how it is incomplete?

Comment: yes @Vishal Chhodwani when i have entered numeric value then it's not accept but when i have press backspace then it's delete all value as a entered please check your side

Comment: @DileepPatel My Pleasure :)